# Balancing account while selecting MySQL rows in descending order - Code Update

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a finance tracker and have run into a bit of a snag with displaying transactions in descending order (most recent to oldest) with a correct running balance.
Here is the SQL I am using:

`SELECT amount, payee, cat, date FROM transactions ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC`

I am using a class to handle the other aspects of this app and the function to display the transactions is part of it. If I were displaying the transactions in ascending order, the following code works as expected:

```
//Fetch the transactions
public function fetchTransactions() {
    global $db;
    $this->getStartingBalance();
    $runningTotal = $this->startingBalance;
    $fetchTransactionsSQL = $db->query("SELECT amount, payee, cat, date FROM transactions ORDER BY id, date");
    while ($transactionDetails = $fetchTransactionsSQL->fetch()) {
        $payee = stripslashes($transactionDetails[payee]);
        $category = $transactionDetails['cat'];
        $amount = money_format("%n", $transactionDetails[amount]);
        $runningTotal = $runningTotal + $transactionDetails['amount'];
        $runningTotalOutput = money_format("%n", $runningTotal);
        echo "
            <tr>
                    <td class=\"payee\">$payee</td>
                    <td>$category</td>
                    <td>$amount</td>
                    <td class=\"runningTotal\">$runningTotalOutput</td>
                </tr>";
    }
}
```

Stuck on trying to display in desc order with the correct running balance - for example, if the value of `$this->startingBalance` was $354.00 and the first (therefore the last displayed in desc order) transaction was for $4.00, the last entry's running balance would be $350.00. The numbers are signed.

Many thanks!

**UPDATED CODE**

Following along the lines of drew010's advice, I remembered a handy little function - array_reverse. I updated the function to include an array for transactions, reversed it, and then iterated through the array to display the transactions in ascending order with the correct running balance.

**Another problem** that I just ran into is the issue of indexing the transactions - for example, displaying only the current month's transactions while maintaining the correct running balance. The updated code below solves the issue of displaying ALL of the transactions in the right order with the correct balance but does not help with the matter of limiting the returned rows.

Here is the updated code, suggestions are appreciated.

```
public function fetchTransactions() {
    global $db;
    $this->getStartingBalance();
    $runningTotal = $this->startingBalance;
    //Array to contain the transactions
    $transactions = array();
    //Counter for transactions array key
    $i = 0;
    $fetchTransactionsSQL = $db->query("SELECT amount, payee, cat, date FROM transactions ORDER BY id, date");
    while ($transactionDetails = $fetchTransactionsSQL->fetch()) {
        $payee = stripslashes($transactionDetails[payee]);
        $category = $transactionDetails['cat'];
        $amount = money_format("%n", $transactionDetails[amount]);
        $runningTotal = $runningTotal + $transactionDetails['amount'];
        $runningTotalOutput = money_format("%n", $runningTotal);
        $transactions[$i] = array("payee" => $payee, "category" => $category, "amount" => $amount, "runningTotal" => $runningTotalOutput);
        $i++; //Increment the array key 
    }
    $transactions = array_reverse($transactions); //Reverse the transactions array to display in ascending order
    //Iterate over transactions array
    foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
        $payee = $transaction['payee'];
        $category = $transaction['category'];
        $amount = $transaction['amount'];
        $runningTotal = $transaction['runningTotal'];
        echo "
            <tr>\n
                <td>$payee</td>\n
                <td>$category</td>\n
                <td>$amount</td>\n
                <td>$runningTotal</td>\n
            </tr>\n
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$this->startingBalance`? Does it get a starting balance for the specified date constraint, if you specify a month?

Comment: The starting balance is the initial balance of the account when it is added to the application. For example. if the user has $359 when they begin, that is saved along with the name and type of account in the Accounts table. The balance is calculated by adding the sum of the transactions (signed integers for amount) to the starting amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. run SUM(amount) FROM transactions
2. Remember result and add it to your $startingBalance and remember that as $endingBalance
3. Run your query to select all transactions in DESC order like you want
4. For each transaction instead of adding $amount to $running balance, substract the $amount from $endingBalance...

Example:
5 Transactions selected in DESC order (amounts only):
1. -7
2. 10
3. 22
4. -17
5. -2
SUM of transactions: $tSum = -7 + 10 + 22 - 17 - 2 = **6**
$startingBalance= **300**
$endingBalance = $startingBalance + tSum = 300 + 6 = **306**

Transactions displayed in desc order:
(AMOUNT | RUNNING BALLANCE)
*END BALANCE: 306*
-7 | 306 ($endingBalance)
10 | 313 ($endingBalanse -= -7)
22 | 303 ($endingBalance -= 10)
-17 | 281 ($endingBalance -= 22)
-2 | 298 ($endingBalance -= -17)
*START BALANCE: 300 ($endingBalance -= -2)*


Your code updated:

```
//Fetch the transactions public 
function fetchTransactions() 
{     
    global $db;
    $this->getStartingBalance();
    $endingBalance = $this->startingBalance + $this->getTransactionsSum();
    $runningTotal = $endingBalance;
    $prevAmount = 0;
    $fetchTransactionsSQL = $db->query("SELECT amount, payee, cat, date FROM transactions ORDER BY id DESC, date DESC");     

    while ($transactionDetails = $fetchTransactionsSQL->fetch()) 
    {         
        $payee = stripslashes($transactionDetails[payee]);         
        $category = $transactionDetails['cat'];         
        $amount = money_format("%n", $transactionDetails[amount]);

        $runningTotal -= $prevAmount;    
        $prevAmount = $amount;

        $runningTotalOutput = money_format("%n", $runningTotal);         

        echo "<tr>                     
                <td class=\"payee\">$payee</td>                     
                <td>$category</td>                     
                <td>$amount</td>                     
                <td class=\"runningTotal\">$runningTotalOutput</td>                 
            </tr>";     
    } 
}

function getTransactionsSum()
{
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS mySum FROM transactions");
    if( $sumFields = $sql->fetch() )
    {
        return money_format("%n", $sumFields[mySum]);
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I hope you have found that helpful...

Comment: This looks VERY promising, will try it out in a little bit. The other issue I'm struggling with is how to put all of this into a Paginated Index without throwing everything off. For example, 30 transactions per page starting with the most recent transaction. Thanks for your help, I think this is it.

Comment: Will think about paginated index and work something out by tomorrow... I am glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm on a 24 hour shift at my "day job," working on this when I can. Congrats on winning the bounty, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the values in ascending order from the point where the starting balance matches up with the first transaction in your query.

Add everything to an array that contains payee, amount, category etc and calculate your balance there.  Then add that array to another array `$transactions[] = $transaction`.

Then when you are ready to output, read backwards from $transactions and output them.

```
for ($i = sizeof($transactions) - 1; $i >= 0; ++$i) {
    $txn = $transactions[$i];
    // output data
}
```

It is a good idea to separate database access from other logic, and separate database and controller logic from your html output for a number of reasons.  See [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start from the current balance and work backwards?  So the first transaction's running balance would be the start balance, then you subtract the current transaction amount from the start balance and that is the running balance of the next transaction.